# jquery.load() doesnt load scripts in partialview

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

when i call

```
$('#test').load('<%= VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Home/Helper") %>', { pass: null });
```

all content is loaded, but

```
<script>...</script>
```

not loading. why??

Comment: When you say "not loading", how do you mean? Does it appear in the DOM if you inspect it with Firebug or suchlike? Also, please post the rendered HTML, not the server-side source code.

Answer (score 1):

This method is the simplest way to fetch data from the server.

It is roughly equivalent to `$.get(url, data, success)` except that it is a method rather than global function and it has an implicit callback function.

When a successful response is detected (i.e. when textStatus is "success" or "notmodified"), .load() sets the **HTML contents** of the matched element to the returned data.

For details refer http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0):

Try using [head.js](http://headjs.com/) insted.